# How to remove specif lines of console out in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a console output into a text file. I am able to write it but I do not want to write last few lines so is there any function to remove specific lines in console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only "remove" current line overriding it with spaces. Just print `CR` (*carriage return*) which is `\r` in java. Then print enough spaces so the line will look clean.

There is no other way to remove certain number of lines. You can execute bash command like `Unix` `clear` or `Windows` `cls` - they will clean whole command line screen. Beware - on `Unix` it works differently then on Windows!